# Does $N \mathbin{\bar{\otimes}} N^{\mathrm{op}}$ act on $L^2(N)$?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $N$ be a von Neumann algebra and $N^{\mathrm{op}}$ its opposite. The standard form $L^2(N)$ is an $N$-$N$-bimodule, or equivalently a module over $N \otimes_{\mathrm{alg}} N^{\mathrm{op}}$.

> Does this make $L^2(N)$ into a module over the spatial tensor product $N \mathbin{\bar{\otimes}} N^{\mathrm{op}}$?

Here's what I know:

- The universal property of the [Dauns tensor product](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1996061) trivially makes $L^2(N)$ into a module over the Dauns tensor of $N$ and $N^{\mathrm{op}}$, but this generally differs from the spatial tensor product.
- Nevertheless, it is true for a type I factor, since $L^2(\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})) = \mathcal{H} \otimes \overline{\mathcal{H}}$, where the left and right action already are on separate tensor factors.

I'm already not sure about the situation for commutative $N$.

Comment: TeX note: once you `\bar` an `\otimes`, TeX forgets that it's a binary operation, and needs to be reminded: $N \bar{\otimes} N$ `N \bar{\otimes} N` vs. $N \mathbin{\bar\otimes} N$ `N \mathbin{\bar\otimes} N`.  I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, $L^2(N)$ is an $N \overline{\otimes} N^\text{op}$ module if and only if $N$ is atomic. The argument in the question basically generalizes as such to atomic $N$. For the no-go part, let me restrict to $N$ having separable predual (although the result is true in general). If $N$ is diffuse, you can choose a faithful normal state $\omega$ on $N$ whose centralizer $N^\omega$ is diffuse. If you now realize the standard representation $L^2(N)$ as the GNS-construction for $\omega$ and if you choose a sequence of unitaries $u_n \in \mathcal{U}(N)$ that converges weakly to zero, it follows on the one hand that $u_n \otimes \overline{u_n} \to 0$ weakly in $N \overline{\otimes} N^\text{op}$, but on the other hand, acting on $1 \in L^2(N)$ and taking the scalar product with $1 \in L^2(N)$, the outcome is $1$ for all $n$. So the module action of $N \otimes_\text{alg} N^\text{op}$ on $L^2(N)$ is not weakly continuous.